# cryptography - BitBox02 firmware signed & public key attached to firmware image for verification

Tags: cryptography, public-key-infrastructure

Bootloader of the *BitBox02* crypto wallet verifies the main application with the public keys that are attached to the firmware update itself. Next to that, there are signatures of the public keys, signed by the company's private key.

- Device holds `3` *root* ECC public keys ([Github permalink](https://github.com/digitalbitbox/bitbox02-firmware/blob/7c9170a8793201491ad9295d43a8820fd721dce4/src/bootloader/bootloader.c#L168-L209)), embedded in the bootloader and immutable
- Firmware image (header part) contains:

  - `3` signing firmware public keys ([Github permalink](https://github.com/digitalbitbox/bitbox02-firmware/blob/7c9170a8793201491ad9295d43a8820fd721dce4/src/bootloader/bootloader.c#L119-L121)), that correspond to some (random?) private keys used for firmware signature,
  - `3` firmware *signatures*, that are verified with the *signing firmware public keys*, attached to the image ([Github permalink](https://github.com/digitalbitbox/bitbox02-firmware/blob/7c9170a8793201491ad9295d43a8820fd721dce4/src/bootloader/bootloader.c#L124-L125)). These keys are used to verify a hash of a firmware image.
  - `3` *Signature* of the double hashed firmware public keys: `signature(sha256(sha256(pubkey)))`. These are verified with the *root* public key ([Github permalink](https://github.com/digitalbitbox/bitbox02-firmware/blob/7c9170a8793201491ad9295d43a8820fd721dce4/src/bootloader/bootloader.c#L122)), means are signed by the *root private keys*, which company holds somewhere.

Process seems to be:

- Device uses *ROOT* public keys to verify the signature of *firmware public keys*
- Device uses *firmware public keys* to verify the signature of the firmware itself.

[image: Verification process]

Does this actually increase the security of the application, compared to directly verifying the firmware with the *root* public key (considering that the firmware is signed by *root* private key)? Image below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It protects the signing process.

The root key can be well protected, as it is only used to sign a small intermediate key.

If the intermediate key that is actually used - and thus has to be distributed to whomever signs the firmware, and perhaps even part of automated build pipelines - is breached, it can be revoked without any huge effects. The root key can simply sign a new intermediate key, and updates can continue.

However, if the root key is compromised you have a bit of a headache. Now you can replace that in every device - but you have to do so *before* invalidating it; otherwise the devices will not trust the update.

So this scheme doesn't improve the security of the particular update, but it improves the usability and security of the overall signature scheme.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought so.

Comment: A second question, does it improve security by means that company has `3` "root" private keys, that are physically at different locations and therefore if one is compromised, attacker still needs to obtain 2 more?